# Managing createdAt timestamp in Firestore

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Every day I am importing products from external retailers into a [Google Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) database.

During that process, products can be either new (a new document will be added to the database) or existing (an existing document will be updated in the database).

Should be noted that I am importing about 10 million products each day so I am **not** querying the database for each product to check if it exists already.

I am currently using [set with merge](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), which is exactly what I need as it creates a document if it doesn't exist or updates specific fields of an existing document.

Now the question is, how could I achieve a createdAt timestamp given that provided fields will be updated, therefore the original createdAt timestamp will be lost on update? Is there any way to not update a specific field if that field already exists in the document?

Comment: What about creating a new dedicated field with a Cloud Function when a doc is created. This field shall not be included in the object you pass to the `set()` method when you update the docs.

Comment: Good point. Will give that a go.

Comment: I've elaborated an answer based on my comment, with the corresponding Cloud Function code. Hope this helps.

Comment: On the Node.js side, the [DocumentSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/DocumentSnapshot#createTime) contains a field for `createTime`.

Comment: @BobSnyder Thanks for the info Bob, interesting to know! Do you suggest that the CF could use `snap.createTime;` as the field value?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec: It's not clear to me.  The documentation for the Admin version of `DocumentSnapshot` is different than `@google-cloud/firestore`.  Not sure if `createTime` is available.

Comment: @BobSnyder See my update to the answer: it works. No idea which method is the best to use however!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest that you use a Cloud Function that would create a new dedicated field when a Firestore doc is created. This field shall not be included in the object you pass to the `set()` method when you update the docs.

Here is a proposal for the Cloud Function code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.productsCreatedDate = functions.firestore
  .document('products/{productId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    return snap.ref.set(
      {
        calculatedCreatedAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      },
      { merge: true }
    )
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
       return false;
    });
  });
```

---

Based on Bob Snyder comment above, note that you could also do:

```
const docCreatedTimestamp = snap.createTime;
return snap.ref.set(
  {
    calculatedCreatedAt: docCreatedTimestamp
  },
  { merge: true }
)
.catch(...)
```

Comment: That looks indeed like what I was after, I'll do some testing tonight and accept the answer if confirmed. Thanks

Comment: Cool. I am interested to know how it behaves when you inject 10 millions document.

Comment: It seems to do the job. It behaves quite nicely, especially when using batch writes. In the end it comes down to how fast you can send documents to it.

Comment: Be very careful with this, updatedAt, for example, will create an infinite loop!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60963531/271450 - In case you're looking for updatedAt

Answer (score 4):

in version firebase 9 the correct way is:

```
import { serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
....
return snap.ref.set(
      {
        calculatedCreatedAt: serverTimestamp();
.....
```