# Universal Firestore trigger for all documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, triggers, google-cloud-functions

How can I trigger a function on any document change in any collection in Firestore? I want to manage `createdAt` and `updatedAt` timestamps. I have many collections and don't want to have to register the trigger for each independently. At that point I might as well just create wrapper functions for `add`, `set`, and `update`.

How can I register a callback that fires when any document is modified?

EDIT:

At this time (2019-08-22), I decided to just create a wrapper function to implement this functionality. The accepted answer does not maintain schema-less-ness. Based on [this article](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-advanced-usage-angularfire/#3-CRUD-Operations-with-Server-Timestamps), I created this `upset` function which manages timestamps and avoids "document does not exist" errors:

```
const { firestore: { FieldValue } } = require('firebase-admin')

module.exports = async function upset (doc, data = {}) {
  const time = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

  const update = { updatedAt: time }
  const updated = { ...data, ...update }

  try {
    const snapshot = await doc.get()

    if (snapshot.exists) {
      return doc.update(updated)
    } else {
      const create = { createdAt: time }
      const created = { ...updated, ...create }

      return doc.set(created)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

Comment: I addition to the answer below, you may have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52660962/how-to-add-timestamp-to-every-collection-insert-update-in-firebase-functions-for/52664157#52664157 (in particular the "HOWEVER" section).

Comment: Referenced article is now paywalled. How do you bind `upset` to every collection/subcollection in all of firestore? Why is it called `upset` instead of `upsert` (`update` + `insert`)?

Comment: To my knowledge it can not be bound. I manually call upset inside my cloud functions whenever I touch a document. The name `upset` is a combination of the two firebase function names, `update` and `set`. `update` + `set` = `upset`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters), you can use wildcards in the document path. More specifically "You may define **as many wildcards as you like** to substitute explicit collection or document IDs"

So, the following Cloud Function will work for documents that are under a root collection:

```
exports.universalFirestoreTrigger = functions.firestore
    .document('{collecId}/{docId}')
    .onWrite((snap, context) => {

        console.log("Collection: " + context.params.collecId);
        console.log("Document: " + context.params.docId);

        return null;

    });
```

If you have sub-collections, you will need to write another Cloud Function, as follows:

```
exports.universalFirestoreTriggerSubCollections = functions.firestore
    .document('{collecId}/{docId}/{subCollecId}/{subDocId}')
    .onWrite((snap, context) => {

        console.log("Collection: " + context.params.collecId);
        console.log("Document: " + context.params.docId);
        console.log("Sub-Collection: " + context.params.subCollecId);
        console.log("Sub-Collection Document: " + context.params.subDocId);

        return null;

    });
```

And so on if you have sub-sub-collections....

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment. At the moment it seems better to just create a wrapper function in order to stay schema-less. If there is no schema-less way, I found this article that provides some examples (in TypeScript): https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-advanced-usage-angularfire/#3-CRUD-Operations-with-Server-Timestamps

Comment: Clearly, using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is the best way to automatically maintain `createdAt` and `updatedAt` timestamps, as explained in the page you refer to (https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-advanced-usage-angularfire/#3-CRUD-Operations-with-Server-Timestamps)

Comment: I added an example implementation to the question.